# Magento 1: search term is not being added back

Tags: magento-1.9, search, catalogsearch, ce-1.9.2.4, search-terms

Ok here is the scenario, I've tested that on a fresh Magento 1.9.2.4 with sample data.

Let's say I have a search term that is "tee".

### 1st Test

- remove all synonyms for "tee"
- delete "tee" from the search terms
- search for "tee" in the frontend
- "tee" is **added back to the search terms**
- add synonyms for "tee" (example: if I edit "t-shirt" search term and I add "tee" in the "Synonym For" entry)
- search for "tee" in the frontend
- "tee" **number of uses is increased by 1**

### 2nd Test

- remove all synonyms for "tee"
- delete "tee" from the search terms
- search for "tee" in the frontend
- "tee" is **added back to the search terms**
- add synonyms for "tee" (example: if I edit "t-shirt" search term and I add "tee" in the "Synonym For" entry)
- **EXTRA STEP HERE:** delete "tee" from the search terms
- search for "tee" in the frontend
- "tee" is **not being added back to the search terms**

### Results

To me, that behavior is totally inconsistent, it should:

- either not increase the number of uses of "tee" in the first step
- or add back "tee" to the search terms with number of uses = 1 in the second step

Thus, the **search reports are not accurate** as if someone search "tee" as it is never added back to the search terms it will not be taken into consideration in the report.

To me it sounds like a bug but I may be missing something.

**Does that behavior sound logic to you and if so could you explain me why ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

### Debugging the issue

Here's the workflow:

Under `app/code/core/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php` in the `indexAction()`, the search term is retrieved by the following code:

```
$query = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery();
```

That corresponds to the following:

```
public function getQuery()
{
    if (!$this->_query) {
        $this->_query = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')
            ->loadByQuery($this->getQueryText());
        if (!$this->_query->getId()) {
            $this->_query->setQueryText($this->getQueryText());
        }
    }
    return $this->_query;
}
```

When you check the resource model `loadByQuery` method, here's what happens:

```
public function loadByQuery(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object, $value)
{
    $readAdapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();
    $select = $readAdapter->select();

    $synonymSelect = clone $select;
    $synonymSelect
        ->from($this->getMainTable())
        ->where('store_id = ?', $object->getStoreId());

    $querySelect = clone $synonymSelect;
    $querySelect->where('query_text = ?', $value);

    $synonymSelect->where('synonym_for = ?', $value);

    $select->union(array($querySelect, "($synonymSelect)"), Zend_Db_Select::SQL_UNION_ALL)
        ->order('synonym_for ASC')
        ->limit(1);

    $data = $readAdapter->fetchRow($select);
    if ($data) {
        $object->setData($data);
        $this->_afterLoad($object);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see, the code here looks for both `query_text` and `synonym_for` results using an `UNION` statement.

The result query would look like this:

```
SELECT `catalogsearch_query`.* 
FROM `catalogsearch_query` 
WHERE (store_id = '1') AND (query_text = 'tee') 
UNION ALL (
    SELECT `catalogsearch_query`.* 
    FROM `catalogsearch_query` 
    WHERE (store_id = '1') AND (synonym_for = 'tee')
) 
ORDER BY `synonym_for` ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Thus:

- in the **1st test, the original term "tee" is retrieved** and thus, its **number of uses is increased by 1 but not the number of uses for the synonyms**
- in the **2nd test, the synonym term "t shirt" is retrieved** and **its number of uses is increased but the original term is not recreated**

Then further in the `indexAction` method we've got the following that takes care of the number of uses increments:

```
if ($query->getId()) {
     $query->setPopularity($query->getPopularity()+1);
}
else {
    $query->setPopularity(1);
}
```

### Fixing the issue

To me there's two possible fixes:

- the first one would be to **use an observer when a search term is deleted so every synonyms for this term are removed.**
- the second one would require a lot more work and would be to **modify the current system totally so it handles the creation of a missing search term when a synonym exists.**

### Side note

I had a look at Magento 2 to see how it handles it.

Funny thing is, Magento 2 does not use `loadByQuery` to get the search term but `loadByQueryText` which looks like this and basically skip the synonym:

```
public function loadByQueryText(AbstractModel $object, $value)
{
    $select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
        $this->getMainTable()
    )->where(
        'query_text = ?',
        $value
    )->where(
        'store_id = ?',
        $object->getStoreId()
    )->limit(
        1
    );
    $data = $this->getConnection()->fetchRow($select);
    if ($data) {
        $object->setData($data);
        $this->_afterLoad($object);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

In Magento 1, this method also exists but it is only used in the backend when a search term is saved.

I assume that synonyms are handled differently in Magento 2 but I have not tested the problem I posted on M2 yet.